# Looks like a simple graphing problem

Tags: math, graph, plot

At present I have a control to which I need to add the facility to apply various acuteness (or sensitivity). The problem is best illustrated as an image:

[Graph http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/7886/control.png](http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/7886/control.png)

As you can see, I have X and Y axess that both have arbitrary limits of 100 - that should suffice for this explanation. At present, my control is the red line (linear behaviour), but I would like to add the ability for the other 3 curves (or more) i.e. if a control is more sensitive then a setting will ignore the linear setting and go for one of the three lines. The starting point will always be 0, and the end point will always be 100.

I know that an exponential is too steep, but can't seem to figure a way forward. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Why the C# tag?  Your solution may ultimately be C#, but I see nothing in the problem that is C#.  Removing the tag...

Comment: Explain the behavior you want. (besides the start/endpoints) Is it exponential? polynomial? logarithmic? It looks like the slope near 0 is linear that then zooms upwards as necessary to meet the endpoint.

Comment: ...or an interpolation between linear and something.

Comment: Just for the benefit of others searching the site, you might want to change the title to something like "What is a good math function for adjusting sensitivity?" or something like that.  And mark the question as answered, if it indeed is. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curves you have illustrated look a lot like [gamma correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) curves.  The idea there is that the minimum and maximum of the range stays the same as the input, but the middle is bent like you have in your graphs (which I might note is *not* the circular arc which you would get from the cosine implementation).

Graphically, it looks like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/74/GammaFunctionGraph.svg/200px-GammaFunctionGraph.svg.png))</sub>

So, with that as the inspiration, here's the math...

If your x values ranged from 0 to 1, the function is rather simple:

```
y = f(x, gamma) = x ^ gamma
```

Add an xmax value for scaling (i.e. x = 0 to 100), and the function becomes:

```
y = f(x, gamma) = ((x / xmax) ^ gamma) * xmax
```

or alternatively:

```
y = f(x, gamma) = (x ^ gamma) / (xmax ^ (gamma - 1))
```

You can take this a step further if you want to add a non-zero xmin.

When gamma is 1, the line is always perfectly linear (y = x).  If x is less than 1, your curve bends upward.  If x is greater than 1, your curve bends downward.  The reciprocal value of gamma will convert the value back to the original (x = f(y, 1/g) = f(f(x, g), 1/g).

Just adjust the value of gamma according to your own taste and application needs.  Since you're wanting to give the user multiple options for "sensitivity enhancement", you may want to give your users choices on a linear scale, say ranging from -4 (least sensitive) to 0 (no change) to 4 (most sensitive), and scale your internal gamma values with a power function.  In other words, give the user choices of (-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4), but translate that to gamma values of (5.06, 3.38, 2.25, 1.50, 1.00, 0.67, 0.44, 0.30, 0.20).

Coding that in C# might look something like this:

```
public class SensitivityAdjuster {
    public SensitivityAdjuster() { }
    public SensitivityAdjuster(int level) {
        SetSensitivityLevel(level);
    }
    private double _Gamma = 1.0;
    public void SetSensitivityLevel(int level) {
        _Gamma = Math.Pow(1.5, level);
    }
    public double Adjust(double x) {
        return (Math.Pow((x / 100), _Gamma) * 100);
    }
}
```

To use it, create a new SensitivityAdjuster, set the sensitivity level according to user preferences (either using the constructor or the method, and -4 to 4 would probably be reasonable level values) and call Adjust(x) to get the adjusted output value.  If you wanted a wider or narrower range of reasonable levels, you would reduce or increase that 1.5 value in the SetSensitivityLevels method.  And of course the 100 represents your maximum x value.

Comment: This was the solution (for me anyway). I tried this and it worked, acheiving everything that I needed. I cannot that you enough Paul, I'd been like a dog "chasing it's tail" on this one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I propose a simple formula, that (I believe) captures your requirement. In order to have a full "quarter circle", which is your extreme case, you would use `(1-cos((x*pi)/(2*100)))*100`.

What I suggest is that you take a weighted average between y=x and y=(1-cos((x*pi)/(2*100)))*100. For example, to have very close to linear (99% linear), take:

```
y = 0.99*x + 0.01*[(1-cos((x*pi)/(2*100)))*100]
```

Or more generally, say the level of linearity is L, and it's in the interval [0, 1], your formula will be:

```
y = L*x + (1-L)*[(1-cos((x*pi)/(2*100)))*100]
```

EDIT: I changed `cos(x/100)` to `cos((x*pi)/(2*100))`, because for the cos result to be in the range [1,0] X should be in the range of [0,pi/2] and not [0,1], sorry for the initial mistake.

Comment: I love simple forumlae. I will certaibnly try this was well tomorrow.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like [polynomial interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation). A quadratic/cubic/quartic interpolation ought to give you the sorts of curves you show in the question. The differences between the three curves you show could probably be achieved just by adjusting the coefficients (which indirectly determine steepness).

Comment: I have looked at that, and interpolation, much like curve fitting is a case where you have a few or more discrete points that you are trying to tie together.v You then use the m = change in x/ change in y to differentiate.

My case is a simple one where I want to either allow a user to enter a variable, or choose from an enum that has Steep, Average and Mild (awful names I know) to allow them to choose the steepness of the curve, much like turning the traction control off on a car and not interpolating the points as there are none at present. I need to generate them.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and AakashM's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The graph of `y = x^p` for `x` from 0 to 1 will do what you want as you vary `p` from 1 (which will give the red line) upwards. As `p` increases the curve will be 'pushed in' more and more. `p` doesn't have to be an integer.

(You'll have to scale to get 0 to 100 but I'm sure you can work that out)

Comment: x^p where p > 1 gives you a slope of 0 near 0. That doesn't look like the curves you've drawn.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for Rax Olgud's general idea, with one modification:

```
y = alpha * x + (1-alpha)*(f(x/100)*100)
```

[alt text http://www4c.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP4501967d41e1aga1b3i00004bdeci2b6be2a59b?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=6](http://www4c.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP4501967d41e1aga1b3i00004bdeci2b6be2a59b?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=6)

where f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1, f(x) is superlinear, but I don't know where this "quarter circle" idea came from or why 1-cos(x) would be a good choice.

I'd suggest f(x) = x<sup>k</sup> where k = 2, 3, 4, 5, whatever gives you the desired degre of steepness for &alpha = 0. Pick a value for k as a fixed number, then vary α to choose your particular curve.

Comment: I believe Rax Olgud chose the quarter circle and a circular function because a circular function moves slowly when it's near one axis and at its fastest when it's near the other axis.

Answer (score 0):

For problems like this, I will often get a few points from a curve and throw it through a curve fitting program. There are a bunch of them out there. [Here's one with a 7-day free trial.](http://www.ncss.com/curve_fit.html?gclid=CM_D0sv-o5sCFShRagodaXOhCQ)

I've learned a lot by trying different models. Often you can get a pretty simple expression to come close to your curve.